# R read.table <-> write.table

Tags: r

In R:

```
d=read.table(filename, as.is = TRUE, header = TRUE, sep = "\t", row.names = 1)
```

What is the command to write back the exact same file from d?

```
write.table(d, ?)
```

I give you one example input file:

```
one two
1   2
```

The separator is "\t". What are the write.table parameters that would write the exact same output file after reading it with read.table?

Thank you,
Gregor

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that your `read.table` used column 1 as `row.names` so it lost its column name ("one"). When you write it out, you have to do something special to get the "one" name back.

`cbind(one=row.names(d), d)` will add the row.names as a column with the name "one". Then you simply have to disable the use of row.names and quotes, and specify the separator:

```
# Create the test file
filename <- "test.txt"
filename2 <- "test2.txt"
cat("one\ttwo\n1\t2\n", file=filename)

# read it in
d <- read.table(filename, as.is = TRUE, header = TRUE, sep = "\t", row.names = 1)

# write it out again
write.table(cbind(one=row.names(d), d), filename2, row.names=FALSE, sep="\t", quote=FALSE)

# Ensure they are the same:
identical(readLines(filename), readLines(filename2)) # TRUE

readLines(filename)
readLines(filename2)
```

**UPDATE** To avoid hard-coding the first column name, you mustn't lose it when loading:

```
# Read the data without any row.names
d <- read.table(filename, as.is = TRUE, header = TRUE, sep = "\t", row.names = NULL)
# Then use the first column as row.names (but keeping the first column!)
row.names(d) <- d[[1]]
d
#  one two
#1   1   2        

# Now you can simply write it out...
write.table(d, filename2, row.names=FALSE, sep="\t", quote=FALSE)

# Ensure they are the same:
identical(readLines(filename), readLines(filename2)) # TRUE
```

You could of course still remove column 1 if you keep the name of it around and use it as in the first example.

Comment: Tnx but i don't want to have something like a name of a column hard-coded in my code (the one=row.names(d) part). That doesn't make it general. Any other ideas?

Comment: Then you must read it in differently! I'll update the answer.

Comment: Tnx: also, i would still like to set the rownames of d as before (read from column 1).

Comment: Great! That was really helpful, tnx a lot.

Answer (score 1):

```
write.table(d,"filename")
```

you have to specify which file extension you want to use. Hope it works.

Comment: Tnx, but unf. that doesn't produce the same output file as the input file.

Comment: @rgregor Did you specify the `sep = "\t"` argument in `write.table`? You'll need to look at all the arguments for `write.table` and pick the correct values for each to specify the exact file format you're interested in.

Comment: joran: thank you, i refined my question. Now it should be more clear. I can't find the right parameters for write.table, can you?

Comment: I did read it but still can't find the right parameters. Could you share with us?

Comment: @rgregor, did you figure it out? If not,can you put an instance of your data?