# Outputting text file and inputting matrix in R?

Tags: r, matrix, text, input, output

I am a beginner at R and I am learning how to output a matrix to a text file in R, and then input that text file back in R to reproduce the original matrix.

```
X.cor #matrix I am dealing with
X_cor.txt <- write.table(X.cor, " ", sep = "\t") #Outputting as text file
X_cor.txt
```

Currently when I do this, I get the following:

```
           [,1]       [,2]      [,3]      [,4]
[1,]  1.0000000 -0.2927700 0.6764814 0.2000000
[2,] -0.2927700  1.0000000 0.5061367 0.8783101
[3,]  0.6764814  0.5061367 1.0000000 0.8568765
[4,]  0.2000000  0.8783101 0.8568765 1.0000000
NULL
```

With the "NULL" referring to the output for the text file. What am I doing wrong here? I am also supposed to take this text file and input it back into R and reproduce X.cor, but name it as X.cor1. Can someone help me with this? Would I use write.table once again?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R read.table <-> write.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9036297/r-read-table-write-table)

Comment: The write.table function returns NULL. It's used for it's side effects. What problem are you having with that concept? If you want to use write.table to save a file, then read it's help page and learn how to use its second argument properly.